# Specifying rows inside formulas in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have two sheets. One is called Dogs and the other is called Interactions.

In the Dogs sheet I have a bunch of info. In the interactions sheet I have these two formulas, in rows one below the other:

```
=Interactions!A4

=OFFSET(Interactions!A4,0,1)
```

What I want is to be able to type a row number in cell A1 and for that row number to be included in the above formulas like this:

```
=Interactions!A*ROWNUMBERFROMCELLA1*

=OFFSET(Interactions!A*ROWNUMBERFROMCELLA1*,0,1)
```

In simpler words, I want the person to say "The interaction is on row x of the spreadsheet" and for the Dog's sheet to then be populated by the data pulled from the offset formulas.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible, but I'm wondering if it's the most elegant solution for what you're trying to do. I'm a fan of the vlookup and filter myself, and if you have the information as I suspect, in rows, you could have each row begin with the key in your Dogs sheet ( lets say, breed for example ), and on the Interactions sheet you set up a pull down menu ( lets say in cel A1 ) for that key using data validation ( criteria List from a Range, hit the select data range button and go to your other sheet, click the first cel, then hold shift while you click the last cel so you end up with something like 'Dogs'!A1:A999 ). Then in the cel next to it on the Interactions sheet you have something like =filter('Dogs'!A1:Z999,'Dogs'!A1=A1) This will look at what you've selected in the pulldown on that sheet ( A1 ) and find the row in the Dogs sheet that has that "key" in the A1 column, returning that entire row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the indirect() function to turn a text string into a cell reference:

```
=INDIRECT("Interactions!A"&A1)

=OFFSET(INDIRECT("Interactions!A"&A1),0,1)
```